# Not able to open the URL with requests.get

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm getting HTTPError: 400 for the below code,i didn't understand why i'm not able to open the url

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import pandas as pd
import re
search_url = f'https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAsoAkIbY2VudHJvLXlhcy1pc2xhbmQtYWJ1LWRoYWJpSDNYBGhsiAEBmAEJuAEGyAEM2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuAKEwOrxBcACAQ&sid=61a721d17d76bc82ccf82c3c3d92de7c&cc1=ae&dist=1&pagename=centro-yas-island-abu-dhabi&srpvid=fee14d92dc160043&type=total&rows=10&offset=0'

page = requests.get(search_url)
print(page)
if page.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
#    get_property_attributes(soup)
else:
    print('open error')

```

```
ouput : <Response [400]>

```
please any one give me some suggestions to overcome the issue
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding headers parameter in the request:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import pandas as pd
import re
search_url = 'https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAsoAkIbY2VudHJvLXlhcy1pc2xhbmQtYWJ1LWRoYWJpSDNYBGhsiAEBmAEJuAEGyAEM2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuAKEwOrxBcACAQ&sid=61a721d17d76bc82ccf82c3c3d92de7c&cc1=ae&dist=1&pagename=centro-yas-island-abu-dhabi&srpvid=fee14d92dc160043&type=total&rows=10&offset=0'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers)
print(page)
if page.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
#    get_property_attributes(soup)
else:
    print('open error')
```

**Output:**

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: above header works on chrome, can we give the same header when we run the code on azure data bricks